# Min/max scaling with additional points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to normalize an array within a range, e.g. [10,100]

But I also want to manually specify additional points in my result array, for example:

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

num_expected = [min(num), 5, max(num)]
expected_range = [10, 20, 100]

result_array = normalize(num, num_expected, expected_range)
```

Intended results:

- Values from 1-5 are normalized to range (10,20].
- `5` in num array is mapped to `20` in expected range.
- Values from 6-8 are normalized to range (20,100].

I know I can do it by normalizing the array twice, but I might have many additional points to add. I was wondering if there's any built-in function in numpy or scipy to do this?

I've checked `MinMaxScaler` in sklearn, but did not find the functionality I want.

Thanks!

Comment: what will be the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear interpolation will do exactly what you want:

```
import scipy.interpolate

interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(num_expected, expected_range)
```

Then just pass numbers or arrays of numbers that you want to interpolate:

```
In [20]: interp(range(1, 9))
Out[20]:
array([ 10.        ,  12.5       ,  15.        ,  17.5       ,
        20.        ,  46.66666667,  73.33333333, 100.        ])
```